# Getting facebook incoming feeds, issue with access token

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I m trying to fetch feeds by graph API using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feeds?access_token=xxxxx
```

I tried with steps for getting short live access token,then using short live access token able to get long live access token

using long live access token i tried to fetch feeds but no data found

so using long live access token ,i tried following code for getting page access token

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=LongLivedToken
```

but it i always found blank page access token.

please suggest which token should i pass for getting incoming feed using graph api

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the permission given to the access_token
to get the facebook feed , u need a read_stream permission from facebook, ie a access token with read_stream.

Comment: our facebook app seems to have all permissions. can you please tell me how can we get access token with read stream, do we need to provide anything from graph api call. I am bit new to this. so please give suggestion on this